# Pass Field Value To URL

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I'd like to create a custom button on the Opportunity object that takes the values of fields on the Opp and passes them to a URL for a custom web form on another site.  Is this possible using Javascript?  If so, can anyone point me to some code samples as I am not Javascript savvy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var pageUrl = '{!URLFOR($Page.yourpage)}'; 
var parameters = '?opptyid={!Opportunity.Id}'; 
var link = pageUrl + parameters; 
window.open(link)
```

If you have a specific URL then provide that url as `pageUrl`

Comment: Thanks.  However, nothing seems to be working.  I am trying to pass values to a Pardot form via URL parameters.  The form was created by a partner company.

Comment: you need to specify what is not working? How partner company expects the parameter to be passed

Comment: What I mean is the code you provided compiles fine and saves in my SFDC instance.  However, the custom Pardot web form does not populate with the values from the Opportunity in my SFDC instance.

Comment: you need to pass the way the form expects. check if you need to do any URL hacking

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use Javascript

Create a custom button on opportunity with similar setup (below screenshot) and add that button to page layout

[image]

I'm passing the country on my contact record to google search page.

Comment: Thanks.  However, nothing seems to be working.  I am trying to pass values to a Pardot form via URL parameters.  The form was created by a partner company.